# Paging in gridview changes only one column data(date), not others

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, paging

I have a problem with paging in gridview. It only updates the first column(date) but not the others. When I check the datatable, I can see all the data loaded but when I change the page in gridview, it only changes the date field data not others.

Following is the code;

```
  protected void btnExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // fetch the data
        DataTable dtExportData = cleanColumnNames(returnGraphData());

        dtExportData = formatTableCellValue(dtExportData);

        // export to xls
        Utility.exportToExcel(new string[] { }, Utility.populateArrayIndex(new string[dtExportData.Columns.Count]),
            dtExportData, "DataView_" + Utility.SanitizeString(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString(), "."), null);
    }

    private void BindGraphGridView(int pageIndex = -1)
    {
        // bind gridview
        this.gvgraph.DataSource = null;
        this.gvgraph.DataSource = returnGraphData();

        this.gvgraph.PageIndex = (pageIndex > 0 ? pageIndex : this.gvgraph.PageIndex);
        this.gvgraph.DataBind();
    }


    protected void gvgraph_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        // paginate...
        gvgraph.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindGraphGridView(e.NewPageIndex);

    }
```

Comment: Check your code in `returnGraphData()`

Comment: I already checked it and it returns all the data needed. However, when the index(page) for gridview changes, it only updates date field...

Comment: Shouldn't `this.gvgraph.DataBind();` before the `this.gvgraph.PageIndex = (pageIndex > 0 ? pageIndex : this.gvgraph.PageIndex);` ?